# How to get a last 15 minutes of a formatted log using a powershell script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to send a email when in the last 15 minutes of a log, a specific error is shown (*ERROR 2915L*) :

Log:

```
2019-08-02T08:36:54 Attempt No : 1
2019-08-02T08:36:54 Connecting to Server
2019-08-02T08:37:15 Attempt No 1 Failed for : ERROR 2915L
2019-08-02T08:37:15
2019-08-02T08:37:15 **********  Error in order  **********
2019-08-02T08:37:15
2019-08-02T08:37:15
2019-08-02T08:37:15 **********  INFORMARION START  **********
2019-08-02T08:37:15  
2019-08-02T08:37:15  
2019-08-02T08:37:15 Request Data : 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VertexEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Login>
    <UserName>Example</UserName>
    <Password>Example</Password>
  </Login>
  <QuotationRequest>
    <Seller>
      <Company>05</Company>
      <Division>01</Division>
      <PhysicalOrigin locationCode="00" />
    </Seller>...
```

---

This is the script that I have so far..

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15) | Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm"
$lastHourLog = get-content 'C:\log.txt' -ReadCount 1000 | foreach { $_ -match $date }
$contains = $lastHourLog | %{ $_ -match 'ERROR 2915L'}
if($contains -contains $true)
{
    #FIRE EMAIL
}
```

I need a way to get the last 15 minutes not just the exact 15 minutes.
log is provided with "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm" format.

Is there a way to make a grater-than with that date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is that not all lines start with a datetime stamp. So you'd have to read the log in raw, then split it so each record starts with a datetime stamp. Then you could filter easily enough.

```
$RawLog = get-content 'C:\log.txt' -Raw
$RecentErrors = $RawLog -split '[\r\n](?=\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)' |Where{[datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-15) -lt $_.Substring(0,19) -and $_ -match 'ERROR 2915L'}
If($RecentErrors){
    <send email>
}
```

This works because PowerShell will, when trying to compare two items, try to convert the item on the right's type to match the item on the left. So when we do `Where{[datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-15) -lt $_.Substring(0,19)` it sees the first item as a `[datetime]` object, and tries to convert the second item to a `[datetime]` as well to perform the comparison.